# Perl: Decoding "garbled" unicode strings

Tags: perl, unicode

I'm working on a CGI script that is called from a piece of software (that I can't change). The variables submitted by the software are giving me problems, because if they contain non-ascii characters they look like this:

`ÿFFFFDEetta er texti meÿFFFFF0 ÿFFFFEDslenskum stÿFFFFF6fum`

instead of

`Þetta er texti með íslenskum stöfum`.

I've tried messing with the `Encode::decode` function but nothing has come of it - all I've gotten it to do is change how the `ÿ` gets represented.

So yeah, I'm kind of stumped. What do I do to change all the `ÿFFFFDE`s into `Þ`s and so on, without resorting to replacing each non-ascii character individually (which is not a solution because this needs to work for languages I don't even speak)?

Comment: It seems that your script is working on octects. Is there a software between your CGI and invoking program? How did you configure that CGI to handle Unicode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use Encode qw(decode);
use Encode::Escape qw();

$_ = 'ÿFFFFDEetta er texti meÿFFFFF0 ÿFFFFEDslenskum stÿFFFFF6fum';
s/ÿFFFF/\\x/g;
decode('iso-8859-1', decode('unicode-escape', $_));
# returns 'Þetta er texti með íslenskum stöfum'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. It was the unicode-escape that eluded me.

Comment: 2007. No longer works :( https://metacpan.org/release/YOU/Encode-Escape-0.14